# Converting a Numeric value fetched from a Dataset to a String Asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, formatting, decimal

I have a numeric value like this in my db,

```
14192555.00
```

when i get it and put it in text box and convert it in to string it results in,

```
this.txtPriorNYSDOTRating.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Fact2A_PriorNYSDOTPerfRatingScore"].ToString();
14192555.0000
```

for it formatting i also tried,

```
this.txtPriorNYSDOTRating.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Fact2A_PriorNYSDOTPerfRatingScore"].ToString("0.####");
```

it result in error "`no overload for method string`"

Hopes for your suggestion thanks in advance

EDITED:

i have date in database like,

```
2010-10-19 00:00:00.000
```

i get it like,

```
10/19/2010 12:00:00 AM
```

my code is,

```
this.txtDesignatedDate.Text =Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DesignatedDate"]).ToString();
```

how to format it to get only `"10/19/2010"

Hopes for your reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert it to double and then apply the format.

```
double d = Convert.ToDouble(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Fact2A_PriorNYSDOTPerfRatingScore"]);
this.txtPriorNYSDOTRating.Text = d.ToString("0.####");
```

Currently it is of `object` type and that doesn't expose `ToString` overload with format parameter.